# C# - How do I infer which generic instance to use, based on the instance which the generic will act-upon?

Tags: generics

I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class Request
{
}
```

It will have implementations:

```
public class ConcreteRequest1 : Request
{
}

public class ConcreteRequest2 : Request
{
}
```

I have a generic handler (abstract and will also have implementations):

```
public abstract class RequestHandler<T> where T:Request
{
    public void Handle(T request){}
}
```

I have a consumer:

```
public class Consumer
{
    // These would be injected via DI
    private RequestHandler<ConcreteRequest1> _handler1;
    private RequestHandler<ConcreteRequest2> _handler2;

    public void Consume(Request request)
    {
        // How do I invoke the correct handler (_handler1 or _handler2)
        // based on the request parameter?

        ???_handler???.Handle(request);
    }
}
```

How do I invoke the correct handler (_handler1 or _handler2) based on the request parameter?  Do I have to use a conditional based on the type of the param?

Comment: You don't mention the language that you use.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a condition in Java to do it because generic types are only known by the compiler and not available any more at runtime. It might be worth considering not to use generics in this case. Another possibility is to use `Class`-objects in addition to generics to distinguish the `RequestHandler`s.

Update: It was clarified that the question is about C#.